# ARM Assembly: declaring a variable visible anywhere in current file & in the program

Tags: assembly, static, arm

My question arose in the process of solving the following exercise:

```
/* Write assembly code to declare variables equivalent to the following C code: */

/* these variables are declared outside of any function */
1) static int foo[3];   /* visible anywhere in the current file */
2) static char bar[4];  /* visible anywhere in the current file */
3) char barfoo;         /* visible anywhere in the program */
4) int foobar;          /* visible anywhere in the program */
```

My questions are:

**How to declare a variable visible anywhere in the program? And, how does it differ from declaring a variable visible anywhere in the current file?**

What I have achieved by far is this:

```
1) foo:  .word  0,0,0,0
2) bar:  .char  0,0,0,0,0
3) 
4)
```

But as you can see I'm having problem with number 3 & 4? how can this be achieved? Of course if I'm wrong with number 1 & 2 please correct me, as it is clear I'm a learner :D.

Thanks a lot.

For reference: my question directly follow an exercise found on chapter 2 of [Modern Assembly Language Programming with the ARM Processor by Larry D. Pyeatt](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0128036982).

The assembler I'm using is GAS.

Comment: Use `EXPORT` or `.GLOBAL` - http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489g/Babeagih.html

Comment: assembly language is specific to the assembler, the program you are using.   What assembler are you using?  You can also look at the output of the compiler you are using as part of your toolchain and see how they declare the label as global.